# Python convert Private Key to RSA Key

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I have a Private Key with the following format

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE6TAbBgkqhki....
----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I convert this in a key with RSA format

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA28jIsb8SAhJritwO....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The current version of cryptography I have is 2.8. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in python but have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230122/encrypted-private-key-to-rsa-private-key)?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I want it to automate it, hence Python.

Comment: What you want to do is to convert a PEM encoded, encrypted PKCS#8 private key to a PEM encoded PKCS#1 private key. Generally you first decode to a Python private key, then reencode it. However, maybe just calling the OpenSSL command line from Python might be a better option in this case. It's a rather strange requirement to convert a a lot of protected private keys to unprotected private keys, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the comment by Maarten Bodewes, a conversion of a encrypted private key in PKCS#8 format to a private key in PKCS#1 format (both PEM encoded) is possible with OpenSSL. But this can also be done with the Cryptography library.

The Cryptography library supports the import of (encrypted) private keys in PKCS#8 format, PEM encoded, with the method [`load_pem_private_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=load_pem_private_key#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_private_key) (since version 0.6), e.g.:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

pkcs8Encrypted = b"""-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICzzBJB...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"""

privateKey = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    pkcs8Encrypted, 
    b'mypassword',
    default_backend()
)
```

The export of private keys in PKCS#1 format, PEM encoded is possible with [`private_bytes()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/?highlight=private_bytes#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateKey.private_bytes) (since version 0.2):

```
pkcs1 = privateKey.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)

print(pkcs1.decode('utf-8')) # -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----...
```

The current version of Cryptography is 3.4.7 (Mar 2021). 2.8 is from Oct 2019, s. [Release history](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#history). Actually, both methods should therefore be available.

Comment: Hi @topaco, thanks for your comment. I did try the same earlier, but somehow its not working for me. Please find the below sample:

private_key:
b'-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE6TAbBgk...\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key, password=passphrase.encode(), backend=default_backend())

I get the following error: 
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.

Comment: @RahulGoud - If the code is running in your environment, the key may be the problem. Then I would try a conversion with OpenSSL, as this is presumably more powerful than the Python implementation. Also, it would be helpful if you could post a **test** key that causes the problem in your environment.