# SSL decryption not generating the begin type correctly

Tags: encryption, openssl, pipeline, pem, sfdx

My context is that I am using jwt token flow to connect to SF in bitbucket pipeline.
I have been able to correctly generate a certificate and key etc as required. I tested the key it is working fine. Next step was to add security, and did not wanted to store my key in the project, thus I encrypted the key like this :

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -in server.key -out server.key.enc -base64 -K <key-value> -iv <iv-value>
```

Now I am storing the encrypted server.key.enc file in my project and then stored the key and iv value as protected bitbucket variables (DECRYPTION_KEY and DECRYPTION_IV)

Now before login to the org, I need to decrypt the server.key.enc to server.key so that I can use this file to login, but when doing so using following cmd, it is not working properly :

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in key/server.key.enc -out key/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
```

The server.key file has only the header malformed but the footer is well generated

**EXPECTED :**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...........
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**GOT :**

```
-��}�5��n�S�*��RIVATE KEY-----
...........
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thus my pipeline finish with following error :
***ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line***

It seems like I missing a small parameter somewhere, but could not locate where.

Comment: The corruption of the first block (first 16 bytes) indicates for CBC a wrong IV. Furthermore the key can be encrypted more conveniently with [openssl-pkey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkey.html), s. e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49230122/9014097).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Topaco, I tried another simpler way to encrypt and decrypt :

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in server.key -out server.key.enc -k <password>
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pbkdf2 -in server.key.enc -out server.key -k <password>
```

as mentioned here : [How to use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files)

And it works better